# Getting extra bullet in return split and map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting extra empty bullet using this global function. I want to next line the strings from the object and layout or return in bulleted
[image]

Here's the data

```
{ 
  target: '● Participates in technical discussions, suggesting possible options for designs and best practices ● Answers customer inquiries promptly',
}
```

Here's my code

```
export function formatString(text) {
 const newText = text.split('●').map(str => <p>● {str}</p>);
 return newText;
}
```

Applying it to another component and passing the parameter
`formatString(target)`

Comment: Do you really need to split by the bullet point if you're just outputting the same bullet point? Or if you're already splitting by the bullet point, perhaps `<ul>` and `<li>` could be a better, more semantic solution?

Comment: Why not have a UL and `li::before { content: '●';`

Comment: `newText = \`<ul>${text.replace(/●/g,'<li>')}</ul>\`;`

Comment: @cbr yes I need that bullet character. Thank you for your inputs

Comment: Thank you @mplungjan will also try to add the character in css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the first bullet point, there is an empty string. Slice the array.

```js
export function formatString(text) {
 const newText = text.split('●').slice(1).map(str => <p>● {str}</p>);
 return newText;
}
```

Comment: Or better, just filter out empty arrays.

Comment: You mean empty strings?

Comment: Ah, yeah, miswrote, empty array elements is what I meant. `.filter(s => s)`

Comment: This works! But how can I assure if first slice is empty?

Comment: It actually will always be if you are splitting by the character at index `0`

Comment: Like @cbr said, use `filter` instead of `slice` and you'll get rid of all of the empty elements of the array, regardless of their position in the array: `const newText = text.split('●').filter(s => s).map(str => <p>● {str}</p>);`

Answer (score 1):

this makes semantically more sense

```
<style> li::before { content: '●'; }</style>
```

combined with

```
newText = `<ul>${text.replace(/●/g,'<li>')}</ul>`;
```

```css
ul {  list-style-type: none; }
li::before {
  content: '● ';
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Participates in technical discussions, suggesting possible options for designs and best practices
  <li>Answers customer inquiries promptly
</ul>
```

If you insist on end `<li>` tags

```
newText = `<ul><li>${text.slice(2).replace(/● /g,"</li><li>")}</li></ul>`)
```

Comment: Since you're mentioning semantics: what about closing tags for the `<li>` elements?

Comment: @Kapobajza Although I always close my tags, LI closing tags are optional in HTML5

Comment: And most browsers will insert the closing tag for me

Comment: I didn't know that and I [did my research](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/syntax.html#optional-tags) now, thank you for teaching me something new.

Comment: @Kapobajza You are welcome. I added `newText = \`<ul><li>${text.slice(2).replace(/● /g,"</li><li>")}</li></ul>\`)` just for you

Answer (score 0):

First element in the returned array from `text.split('●')` is an empty string.

```
'x lorem ipsum'.split('x')
// => ["", " lorem ipsum"]
```